# How to install editbin.exe without installing an entire Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, msbuild, dockerfile

I am trying to move my current build server, which is based on Visual Studio, to a containerized environment. As such, I am trying to use the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2019` image available on docker hub.

One step required during the build is to remove the `NXCOMPAT` flag from the resulting executable ([more details available here for the why](http://jasper-net.blogspot.com/2011/05/nxcompat-and-c-compiler.html)). To do so, I need to use `editbin.exe` which ships with Visual Studio. The current image version does not include it. So I would like to add it myself as I already have to customize the image a bit to fit my needs.

Which package can I install to get `editbin.exe` working in my docker image?

I don't want to install a full Visual Studio as it will defeat the purpose of using the dotnet sdk image. I am not even sure I can as the container is not running in an interactive mode.

I originally reported my issue to the `microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker` [repo here](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/issues/300).

Comment: Have you looked into install just the build tools for vs 2017? Like from nuget?

Comment: The build tools for visual studio are already part of the `dotnet/framework/sdk` image

Comment: Can you provide the link @GGirard?

Comment: This should be the one I am using https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/master/4.7.2/sdk/windowsservercore-ltsc2019/Dockerfile

Comment: No the link for hub.docker.com

Comment: Is this it? https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-sdk/

Comment: yes this is the one

Comment: I asked this question once, I'll look for it. In the end I managed to solve it, but not optimally. That is, I may have installed more components than necessary.

Comment: I hope I remember to add the `Dockerfile` as an answer. If not, you might want to remind me.

Comment: @Baruch thanks for your post, it indeed contains the information I was looking for. It was a bit tricky in my case as I didn't have the C++ workload installed on my machine. The editbin.exe I have been using for years now was part of an internal SDK of Visual Studio. This article helped a lot too https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/finding-the-visual-c-compiler-tools-in-visual-studio-2017/